# Delete all product from one of storeviews

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, products, delete

considering that I can not go to adminpanel--> catalog-->product page due to errors I have, how can I delete all products from one of my store views?

Answer (score 0):

Try This code :-

```
<?php
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin');
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
        Mage :: app("default") -> setCurrentStore( Mage_Core_Model_App :: ADMIN_STORE_ID );
        $products = Mage :: getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->setStoreId(1)->getAllIds();
        if(is_array($products))
        {
            foreach ($products as $key => $pId)
            {
                try
                {
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pId)->delete();
                  
                } 
                catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    echo "Could not delete product with ID: ". $pId ."<br />";
                }
            }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Due to my limit access I couldn't run the code. I will accept as soon as I try it.

Comment: You might want to be careful running that, make sure you backup before hand. But wont you need to remove it from the store view by getting the store views from the product and unsetting the one which you require - delete would completely delete the product from the whole install i think?